# Nginx config: location block only for main page without get paremeters

Tags: nginx

```
location ~* ^\/$ {
    proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host                    $host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    break;
}
```

Currently domain.com/?get=parameters goes to port 8888, but need to go to 80 port.

How to complete location block?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this [is_args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24is_args) variable available in `nginx`. Give it a try the below condition in your above conf. block:

```
if ($is_args != "") {
    proxy_pass                  http://127.0.0.1:80;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: No no, not a solution for me. :)

Comment: @Beck didn't get you? What do you mean not a solution for you?